# Getting unexplained uninitialised constant error in Ruby for a hello world program

Tags: ruby

I have the following code in ruby:

```
Class Sample
    def hello
        puts "Hello"
    end 

s = Sample.new
s.hello
```

The error I'm getting is

> my_prog.rb:1:in '': uninitialized constant Sample (NameError).

Why am i getting this error message?

Comment: I'm guessing you're a Python programmer...  In ruby indentation is irrelevant to the interpreter, you need to close out blocks explicitly.

Comment: Haha you're right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax for declaring classes is invalid. Try:

```
class Sample
  def hello
    puts 'Hello'
  end
end

Sample.new.hello
```

Also note that unlike languages like java, you don't need a *"main"* class/method.

```
puts 'Hello'
```

will suffice

Answer (score 2):

There is a silly mistake in your code. You should change a little bit code.
you have given Class Sample instead of class Sample so ruby interpreter could not find Sample class in my_prog.rb while you are calling a new object of Sample class
You can use below code

```
class Sample
    def hello
        puts 'Hello'
    end
end

sample = Sample.new
sample.hello
```